# Excel VBA Open Msg Title

Tags: excel, vba, function, msgbox

I'm trying to prompt the user to open a file, but the title says something other than Open. I know that there exists MsgBox and a function to prompt open(that I'm not familiar with). I was wondering if there exists some combination of the MsgBox and that function so that instead of the open title on the open prompt I can insert my own instruction. The file collected from this function would then be collected for later use.

I'm trying to avoid inserting both the MsgBox and another function for the open prompt. If this is possible any assistance is appreciated, if not thank you anyways.

Comment: This isn't very clear. Perhaps showing your code would help. In any event, you can make your own user form if neither `MsgBox` nor the built-in file-picker works to your satisfaction. For information on how to use the file picker function see this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-filedialog-property-excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for a [FileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-filedialog-property-excel) as per John's comment.

The example below will show a FileDialog and return the path of the file selected. If the dialog is cancelled, the return value will be `vbNullString`.

You could pass the default path as a parameter to the function as well as the file extension for the Filter.

---

```
Public Function OpenFileDialogToString() As String
    On Error GoTo Trap

    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With fd
        .Title = "Dialog Title"
        .InitialFileName = "Dialog start-up path"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Text Documents (*.txt)", "*.txt", 1
        .ButtonName = " Open "
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
    End With

    If fd.Show <> 0 Then OpenFileDialogToString = fd.SelectedItems(1)

Leave:
    Set fd = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
Exit Function

Trap:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical 
    Resume Leave
End Function
```

---

To call it:

```
Dim path As String
path = OpenFileDialogToString()

If path <> vbNullString Then Debug.Print path
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I have one question If I wanted to use the file name (for thisWorkbook.activate) would I use path.activate?Also thank you once again!!

Comment: The dialog simply selects a file in a folder and returns its path as a string. If you want to open the selected file, use `Workbooks.Open(path)`.

Comment: I saw it passing as a string, I was just wondering if I was correct in connecting path as the holding the name. Thanks again!!